# WPF textblock shifts with placement of attribute

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

Why is it when using the different ways of expressing attributes the textblock shifts?

```
<TextBlock  Canvas.Left="0"  Canvas.Top="0"  FontSize="72" >
        <TextBlock.Foreground>Red
        </TextBlock.Foreground>

        DIET
    </TextBlock>
```

verses

```
    <TextBlock  Canvas.Left="0"  Canvas.Top="0"  FontSize="72" Foreground="Red">

        DIET
    </TextBlock>
```

The later is more left then the first.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is no reason for this and there isn't any difference, just a bug in the **Visual Studio Designer**. Try it in runtime and see for yourself :)

Comparison between **Visual Studio 2010 Designer**, **Blend** and **Runtime** with the following Xaml

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="72">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>Red</TextBlock.Foreground>
        DIET
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100" FontSize="72" Foreground="Red">
        DIET
    </TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How much to the left? It may be due to [Subpixel sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) - the red LED of a pixel may be on its left side and it will look as if the text has shifted by 2/3 of a pixel. Try Foreground="Blue" and if its shifted slightly to the right, then this is the problem. Just live with it.

Comment: No no - this is many many pixels - about just a guess 50 or so.